# Http soap request doesn't return anything

Tags: java, apache, http, soap

I'm trying to do a soap request via a http post. According to this https://t4t.services.telenet.be/TelemeterService?wsdl that shows https://t4t.services.telenet.be/TelemeterService?xsd=1

I need to post a Id and password.

This is my request:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        callWebService("retrieveUsage");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void callWebService(String soapaction) throws IOException {
    String body = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/\" xmlns:tns=\"http://www.telenet.be/TelemeterService/\" xmlns:wsdl=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" ><SOAP-ENV:Body><mns1:RetrieveUsageRequest xmlns:mns1=\"http://www.telenet.be/TelemeterService/\"><UserId>test</UserId><Password>test</Password></mns1:RetrieveUsageRequest></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://t4t.services.telenet.be/TelemeterService");

    // Request parameters and other properties.
    StringEntity stringentity = new StringEntity(body, "UTF-8");
    stringentity.setChunked(true);
    httppost.setEntity(stringentity);
    httppost.addHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
    httppost.addHeader("SOAPAction", soapaction);
    //Execute and get the response.
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    String strresponse = null;
    if (entity != null) {
        strresponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    }
    System.out.println(strresponse);
    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

I'm using apache http.

The strresponse is empty.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: what is the http response code?

Comment: Status code 415. This means my body isn't correct. I just don't see the error :s

Comment: Use something like SoapUI to make a call and use an http proxy like charles proxy to watch the http exchange.  then use the http proxy to watch your http exchange.  figure out what the differences are and fix your bugs.